# Invalid hook call. React hooks

Tags: react-hooks

error:

> Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body
>   of a function component. This could happen for one of the following
>   reasons

Hello I am trying to use useDispatch in my action but it is generating this error from invalid hoook

I can't solve it

can anybody help me?

my action

```
import {FETCH_FAIL,FETCH_LOADING,FETCH_SUCESS} from './actionType';
import api from '../../../services/api';
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";

const FetchSucess = data  => (console.log(data),{
    type:FETCH_SUCESS,
    data
});
const FetchFailed = error  => ({
    type:FETCH_FAIL,
    error
});
const isLoadingFetch = () => ({type: FETCH_LOADING})


export default function AllProducts  () {
    const dispatch = useDispatch()
    dispatch(isLoadingFetch());
    // fetching data
    api.get('/products')
        .then( response => { dispatch(FetchSucess(response.data))})
        .catch( err => { dispatch(FetchFailed(err.message));});
}
```

my component

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

export default function Cards() {
        useEffect(() => {
          // This will be invoked only once.
          getAllProducts();
        }, []);

        const classes = useStyles();
        const classes2 = useStyles2();

        const products = useSelector(state => state.data.filteredProducts);



        return (

            <div className="App">
            <Container maxWidth="md" className={classes.root}>
            <Grid container md={4} spacing={1} ></Grid>
            <Grid container md={8} spacing={1} alignItems={"center"}>
            {products.map(product => (
                <Grid item lg={4} md={4} sm={12} xs={12}>
          <Card className={classes2.card}>
              <CardMedia
                className={classes2.media}
                image={
                  "https://www.theclutch.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2019/11/skins-csgo-neymar.jpg"
                }
              />
              <CardContent className={classes2.content}>
                <Typography
                  className={classes2.name}
                  variant={"h6"}
                  gutterBottom
                >
                  {product.name}
                </Typography>
                <Typography
                  className={classes2.price}
                  variant={"h1"}
                >
                 {util.formatCurrency(product.price)}
                </Typography>
              </CardContent>
            </Card>
                </Grid> 
            ))}
            </Grid>
            </Container>
          </div>
        );
    }
```

Comment: As the error states, hooks are meant to be used inside a React Function Component.  `AllProducts` is just a function, it's not a React component.  What is `AllProducts` and where/how do you intend to use it?  (Currently it's not used at all.)

Comment: All product is my action where I use axios to take a route on my back end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on this comment above:

> All product is my action

If `AllProducts` is a Redux action that needs to perform an async operation and dispatch other actions in response to that operation, there's a convention available by which Redux will pass `dispatch` as a function argument.  The action just needs to return a function which accepts that argument.  For example:

```
export default function AllProducts () {
    return function(dispatch) {
        dispatch(isLoadingFetch());
        // fetching data
        api.get('/products')
            .then( response => { dispatch(FetchSucess(response.data))})
            .catch( err => { dispatch(FetchFailed(err.message));});
    }
}
```

There's no need to use the hook, that's only necessary within React Function Components or within other hooks (which themselves are used within React Function Components).

Comment: I tested with this function debugging and it does not enter inside my return

Comment: It calls my function all product and does not enter my return function dispatch.

Comment: @Felipe: How did you test it?  Please show how you're calling your action.  (Are you dispatching *that* call?)

Comment: i import : import getAllProducts from '../store/actions/fetch/index' and use useEffects             useEffect(() => {
      getAllProducts();
    }, []);

Comment: i try with this and nothing:     const dipatch = useDispatch();
    useEffect(() => {
      getAllProducts(dipatch);
    }, []);

Comment: @Felipe: `AllProducts` and `getAllProducts` are two different things.  For your second comment... You're not using `dispatch` correctly.  To dispatch a Redux action (which you *already do* elsewhere) you would *invoke* the `dispatch` function: `dispatch(getAllProducts())`

Comment: thank you so much, could you just ask me one more question?

so my front end only calls my back end once,
if my backend is off and I enter my products that I call backend won't show up

and if I turn on my back end my products will only appear after I refresh the page,

the only way out is to use server socket?

Is there any possibility other than with the server socket?

Comment: @Felipe: Without using a web socket (which is the preferred approach if possible), a fallback option could be to have an ongoing polling operation from the front-end.  Maybe every 30 seconds or so (with `setInterval`) it checks the back-end for updated information.  If possible, once it finds the back-end is working again it should then attempt to re-establish a web socket instead of continuing to poll, as ongoing polling when data rarely updates is inefficient.

Comment: thanks brother @David, 
so the best option would be using websocket?